# how do I make a table to display ratio between male and female by decade from different tables sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, union

I'd like to display the ratio between SEX by decade how male and female compare to each decade adding table 1 and 2 together

It should look like this:

| Year | Sum of male | Sum of female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | ### | #### |
| 2010 | ##### | ### |

```
sql = ("Select "
           "sum(case when SEX LIKE 'Male%' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when SEX LIKE 'Female%' then 1 else 0 end), YEAR/10*10"
           "from table 1"
           "UNION ALL"
           "sum(case when SEX LIKE 'Male%' then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when SEX LIKE 'Female%' then 1 else 0 end),Year/10*10 "
           "from table2"
           " where table1.YEAR AND table2.Year != ' ' "
           "group by table1.YEAR/10 ")
```

Here's my code and the best I could create was two tables who listed out male and female separately by decades but I wasn't able to sum up the values in each decade by male or female in just one summarized table in order to produce ratio

Comment: can you please add both tables and data with it see  [why should i provide a minimal reproducible example for a very simple sql query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following demonstrates:-

- a) how only a single table is required, and
- b) how the `CASE` construct is also not required.

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (year INTEGER, sex TEXT);
/* LOAD DATA */
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    (2000,'male'),(2000,'male'),(2001,'male'),(2002,'male'),(2003,'male'),
    (2004,'male'),(2010,'male'),(2011,'male'),(2012,'male'),(2013,'male'),
    (2000,'female'),(2000,'male'),(2001,'female'),(2002,'male'),(2003,'female'),
    (2004,'male'),(2010,'female'),(2011,'male'),(2012,'female'),(2013,'male'),
    (2005,'whatever'),
    (2023,'niether')
;

/* DEMO */
SELECT 
    (year / 10) * 10 AS decadestart,
    ((year / 10) * 10) + 9  AS decadeend, 
    count(sex) AS total, 
    sum(sex = 'male') AS m, 
    sum(sex = 'female') AS f, 
    sum(sex <> 'male' AND sex <> 'female') AS o,
    /* percentages*/
    round((CAST((sum(sex = 'male')) AS REAL) / count(sex)) * 100,3) AS mp,
    round((CAST((sum(sex = 'female')) AS REAL) / count(sex)) * 100,3) AS fp,
    round((CAST((sum(sex <> 'male' AND sex <> 'female')) AS REAL) / count(sex)) * 100,3) AS op
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY year/10
;
/* CLEANUP */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
```

Resulting in:-

[image]